# artitrying to ant debug my first android project on linux and getting following error

Tags: android

BUILD FAILED
/home/bhaskar/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:650: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/bhaskar/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:691: null returned: 1

Total time: 1 second

```
<aapt executable="${aapt}"
                command="package"
                verbose="${verbose}"
                manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                originalManifestPackage="${project.app.package}"
                androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                rfolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
                nonConstantId="${android.library}"
                libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
                ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}"
                binFolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
            <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
            <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
        </aapt>
```

particularily the line it says is : proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">

Comment: is `/home/bhaskar/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml` your file?

Comment: Can you post the function where the error occurs?